# Add product to quotes based on quote record type

Tags: trigger

How can I have quote lines auto populated based on quote record type?

I have 6 record types and each requires specific part numbers to be added to the quote
e.g. 1 Purchase record type requires Capital product, Service Product and Consumables
e.g. 2 Rental record type, only lists the rental fee part number

I am not experience with triggers, is there any other way to create this type of child records?

Answer (score 1):

Are you experienced with code at all? It seems to me like triggers would be the only way to do this automatically.

[There is some code available on developer force which could be utilised to help clone a quote with it's children](http://developer.force.com/projectpage?id=a063000000EWWYrAAP). You could use that along with some 'template' quotes (I *don't* mean quote templates, the layouts for actual quotes) and then clone instead of creating new ones each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could design a flow to create the new quote record and create the children records. You'd still have to use a little code to redirect the visualforce page to the new record after it was created (example here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F000000097pVIAQ) but it is probably less code than writing triggers.